# Fetch api status is 200 but not showing data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, fetch-api

I'm trying to get a list of locations in the `ASP.NET MVC` application using fetch API its hits the action method
and response code is 200 but how can I access data in response

```
$('#sendbtn').click(function () 
{
    fetch('/Accounts/getlogic')
        .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
})
```

and in the controller

```
public void getlogic()
{
    var list = db.Locations.ToList();
    Response.Write(Json(list));
}
```

Comment: your method is void, how can it return data?
it should be a public method decored with [HttpGet] and return something

Comment: Why are you writing to the response stream directly?  Have you done any MVC tutorials?